# Make: Combining Pattern Rules and Wildcards in a Target Dependency

Tags: makefile, wildcard, gnu-make

I have a few PDFLaTeX main files called `ch*.tex` with numbers replacing the asterick, a PDF file printed by compiling `ch*.tex` called `ch*.pdf`, and several LaTeX files input into each `ch*.tex` during compile that are saved into their respective `ch*/` directories. With a Makefile I want my `ch*.pdf` files to be compiled by `ch*.tex` files, with TeX files in the `ch*` subdirectory as additional dependencies, **without hardcoding** each `ch*` instances.

However, in some cases the `ch*` subdirectory may not exist. This changes as my LaTeX projects develops, as some `ch*.tex` files may be split into subfiles while others may just be one big block file of code. So I want my Makefile to use `ch*` subdirectory files as dependencies if they exist, but not if they don't. Here are some failed trials:

```
%.pdf : %.tex %/*.tex
  pdflatex $<
```

This trial successfully detects existing files in the `ch*` subdirectory, but fails to compile if there is no `ch*` directory at all.

```
%.pdf : %.tex $(wildcard %/*.tex)
  pdflatex $<
```

This trial doesn't recognise `$(wildcard %/*.tex)` as a dependency and only uses `ch*.tex`.

How can I use files in the `ch*` subdirectory (without using files in other subdirectories) as dependencies for its respective `ch*.pdf` compilation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to use [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

%.pdf : %.tex $$(wildcard $$*/*.tex)
        pdflatex $<
```